# how to check mothly payment(emi) is paid or not?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables emi and emi_details.

Emi table contains:

- id
- company_name
- loan_amount
- interest_rate
- emi_amount
- deposited_amount
- deadline (monthly)
- balance
- created_at
- updated_at

And Emi Details table contains

- id
- emi_id
- date
- amount
- fine
- interest
- created_at
- updated_at

Here, Emi is created for a vehicle at first and then monthly emi is added to emi details table.

I want to check monthy emi is paid or not and want to notify 3 days before dead line.

How can I do using these dates ?
Any help, suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: have you done something to get this  ? if not than hire some one and make it. this site is only for correct your error

Comment: I am looking for some logic about the problem and I don't need code for free.

Comment: Did my answer help you? Have you had trouble with it?

Comment: I have not understand too much about task scheduling from the laravel docs. I have learn something from your answer and finally solved my problem. Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel allows you to [schedule cron tasks](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) daily, weekly, monthly, etc.

Basically you have to register the Laravel tasks on your server:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

If you don't have access to the cron tabs, you can always [use this service](https://forge.laravel.com).

Then you will need to create your two commands:

```
php artisan make:command CheckEmiIsPaid
php artisan make:command NotifyEmi
```

…and register them in Laravel's Scheduler (`App\Console\Kernel`):

```
// ...

protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\CheckEmiIsPaid::class,
    \App\Console\Commands\NotifyEmi::class,
];

// ...

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->command(CheckEmiIsPaid::class)->monthly();
    $schedule->command(NotifyEmi::class)->daily();
}
```

Then, all you have to do is write the logic in CheckEmiIsPaid.php and NotifyEmi.php to fetch your records, check for payments, compare the dates and send the notifications.